# What is wrong with this python code or idle?

Tags: python, sorting

When i created the bubble() it can sort the mine list but when i give while loop outside of def function it did not sort the list.

"}}" -is ">>>" in python idle.

Problem for me looks like, this while loop work in def function but not works at outside.

```py
}}def iftrue(a):

    for i in range(len(a)-1):
        if a[i]>a[i+1]:
            return False
    return True

}}def bubble(a):

    c=0
    while not iftrue(a):
        for i in range(len(a)-1):
            if a[i]>a[i+1]:
                a[i],a[i+1] = a[i+1],a[i]
                c+=1
    return a,c

}} bubble([1,2,3,4,5,6,5,5,4,3,2,1])

([1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6], 30)

}} a

[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6, 4, 3, 2, 1]

}} while not iftrue(a):

        for i in range(len(a)-1):
            if a[i]>a[i+1]:
                a[i],a[i+1] = a[i+1],a[i]


}} a

[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6, 4, 3, 2, 1]
```

Comment: Works for me: my final a is sorted. I'm using the command line Python though not IDLE.

Comment: It works fine for me. in Python 3.4.5 command line, and also as an executable Python script.

Comment: Also works on repl.it: https://repl.it/@RupW/so56810615

Comment: works for me in Idle and command line.